# Enterprise Architect (C++): Import Source Code with Custom Macro and Argument in Parantheses

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I want to reverse engineer models from source code with Enterprise Architect 11. The class definitions look like:

```
class MYCUSTOMMACRO(className) : public baseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, EA skips these classes, as the macro was not recognized. If I define a language macro in EA, `MYCUSTOMMACRO(className)` is skipped as a whole. This, again, produces a parsing error, as the class name is missing.

So, is there a way to extract the class name out of the macro and import the classes?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: You might experiment with preprocessing your code (e.g. `g++ -E`, `cl /E`) - which will expand the macros - then letting this "EA" thing chew on that....

Comment: why don't you just run the files through the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work by creating your own MDG technology file based off the following:

```
<MDG.Technology version="1.0"><Documentation id="0" name="Customer Code Module" version="1" notes="Allows using a Customer Macro as an identifier"/>
<CodeModules><CodeModule language="C++" notes=""><CodeOptions><CodeOption name="PrependGrammarDefinitions">
                    <![CDATA[
<identifier>            ::= "MYCUSTOMMACRO" "(" <> ")"      

]]>
</CodeOption>
</CodeOptions></CodeModule></CodeModules>
</MDG.Technology>
```

Save the code as an XML file i.e. prependgrammer.xml.

Once created you can activate it by the Extensions | MDG Technologies... dialog then hit the "Advanced..." button, then Add.

Now you can just import the C++ as per normal and it should pick up your "MYCUSTOMMACRO" defined class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Imported the xml file as you suggested (in EA11: Settings -> MDG Technologies), but the outcome is still the same. Importing the sourcing file yields the following error:
    There was an error parsing ..\MyClass.h  on line 19.  Unexpected symbol: :

Comment: Hey owang, the above is just and example, the <identifier> line will need to be modified to suit the syntax of your codefile. If you could post it up I could take a look for you.