# Extend enterprise architect grammar for C++ with custom macros

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I want to reverse engineer some C++ files in my Enterprise Architect model. Some methods in my C++-Source are prefixed with a custom macro

```
     class Model
     {
     public:
       Model();
       MACRO1 void method1();
       MACRO2 void method2();
     }
```

I've added MACRO1 and MACRO2 to the list of preprocess macros to make it work at all.
But now I would like to set the stereotype of the method1 & method2 to MACRO1/ MACRO2 during the import of the source code. Is this somehow possible?

I think a similar problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131308/enterprise-architect-c-import-source-code-with-custom-macro-and-argument-in/31554300#31554300), but I can't get it to work. The biggest problem I have in understanding is whether I would have to define a complete BNF for C++ on my own or whether I could somehow extend the parser of Enterprise Architect.

Thank you very much,
 sitob80

Comment: Comments also propose to use post preprocessed-code.

Answer (score 1):

I ask Sparx System for support for something very similar (I want to add comment delimiters to import Doxygen comments).

Short answer is : you can't.

Long answer is : you could try to write your own grammar to fit your use case. Unfortunately there is no starting point for C++ (the simple sample language example is far from complete) and Sparx System cannot provide a C++ sample.

Maybe these can help :

- http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/mdg_tech/
- http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/creatingmdgtechnologies.html

You could also try to create an extension to do that and parse your code in any language your comfortable with.

The answer from Sparx System support was :

> "Sorry, we don't provide the option for users to modify our base C++ import grammar or provide the source for it."

EDIT : Note that you can, however, modify the code generation templates.